# Why is my program matching the wrong values?

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm making a battleship game. I can't figure why, when you overlap a ship in **n** different locations, my program will ask you to input a different starting position **n** times.

```
def make_ships(name, length, position, orientation):
    ships[name] = {"length": length, "Coordinates": {}}
    x = ord(position[:1])
    y = int(position[1:])
    coords = {}
    if orientation.lower() == "y":
        for i in range(0, length):
            place = ''.join([chr(x), str(y)])
            coords[place] = "-"
            x = x + 1
    elif orientation.lower() == "n":
        for i in range(0, length):
            place = ''.join([chr(x), str(y)])
            coords[place] = "|"
            y = y + 1
    print("Coordinates of incoming ship: {}".format(list(coords.keys())))
    names = []
    for item in ships:
        names.append(item)
        # a.append(list(self.ships[item]["Coordinates"].keys()))
    for var in names:
        for item in coords.keys():
            if item in list(ships[var]["Coordinates"].keys()) and ships[name] != ships[var]:
                print("Coordinates of {}: {}".format(var, list(ships[var]["Coordinates"].keys())))
                new_position = input("There is an overlap at {}. Please enter a different starting position: ".format(item)).replace(" ","")
                new_orientation = input("Is it horizontal? (Y/N): ").replace(" ","")
                make_ships(name, length, new_position, new_orientation)
    ships[name]["Coordinates"] = coords

ships = {}
ships["Aircraft Carrier"] = {}
ships["Aircraft Carrier"] = {"length": 5, "Coordinates": {'a1':'|', 'a2':'|', 'a3':'|', 'a4':'|', 'a5':'|'}}
make_ships("Battleship", 4, 'a1', 'n')
```

The battleship in the original call overlaps the existing carrier in 4 locations.
The program asks you to enter a new location and orientation.
If you pick, say, **b1**, the program claims an overlap and shows the coordinates of the carrier, **a1-a5**, which obviously do *not* overlap a ship in **b1-b4**.

Comment: What indentation needs to be fixed?

Comment: I fixed it.  You failed to indent the function.

Comment: "Battleship" is actually set to start at `a1`, which is the same as "Aircraft Carrier". Can you check? Or I may misunderstood something.

Comment: the problem is when 2 ships overlap. So I set that up from the get-go. When you run the code it asks you to pick a new starting location. No matter what you pick it will ask you to pick a new starting location at least 4 times. That is the problem I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**PROBLEM**

Your mistake was using a recursive call to **make_ships**, instead of a simple iteration (**while loop**).  When the first entry fails with a match on space **a4**, you get the new ship's information and add it nicely.  However, you then return from the recursive call to the first call, *where you are still in the checking loop*.  That iterates to the next space in the a-column checking, finds that **a1** of your *original* call also matches (if you're stubborn, you'll get this four times, once for each collision from the original battleship).

**REPAIR**

The clean way is to replace this process with a "read until good" while loop.  The pseudo-code for that is:

Get first input
   while input is unacceptable
       get replacement input

The cheap way is to simply put a **return** after the recursive call.  My code for that, including my debugging instrumentation, is below.  When I tested this, I put the replacement battleship at square q7 :-) which made it obvious that the problem had nothing to do with the ships touching.

```
def make_ships(name, length, position, orientation):
    print ("===> ENTER make_ships", name, length, position, orientation)
    ships[name] = {"length": length, "Coordinates": {}}
    x = ord(position[:1])
    y = int(position[1:])
    coords = {}

    if orientation.lower() == "y":
        for i in range(0, length):
            place = ''.join([chr(x), str(y)])
            coords[place] = "-"
            x = x + 1
    elif orientation.lower() == "n":
        for i in range(0, length):
            place = ''.join([chr(x), str(y)])
            coords[place] = "|"
            y = y + 1
    print("Coordinates of incoming ship: {}".format(list(coords.keys())))

    # Validating for ship overlap
    names = []
    for item in ships:
        names.append(item)
        # a.append(list(self.ships[item]["Coordinates"].keys()))
    for var in names:
        # print ("coords.keys=", coords.keys())
        for item in coords.keys():
            print ("\ncoords.keys=", coords.keys())
            print ("var=", var, "\tname=", name, "\titem=", item)
            print (ships[var]["Coordinates"].keys())
            if item in list(ships[var]["Coordinates"].keys()) and ships[name] != ships[var]:
                print("Coordinates of {}: {}".format(var, list(ships[var]["Coordinates"].keys())))
                new_position = input("There is an overlap at {}. Please enter a different starting position: ".format(item)).replace(" ","")
                new_orientation = input("Is it horizontal? (Y/N): ").replace(" ","")
                make_ships(name, length, new_position, new_orientation)
                return

    ships[name]["Coordinates"] = coords

    print ("===> EXIT make_ships", coords)


ships = {}
ships["Aircraft Carrier"] = {}
ships["Aircraft Carrier"] = {"length": 5, "Coordinates": {'a1':'|', 'a2':'|', 'a3':'|', 'a4':'|', 'a5':'|'}}

make_ships("Battleship", 4, 'a1', 'n')
```

Comment: Ok, I looked into that before I ran into this problem, the rest of my program had made the switch from recursive to while loops and it seemed easier to leave this one. But apparently that's bad habit.

Comment: Yes, it's a bad habit -- more because it leaves your mind less sharp to differentiate recursive and iterative processes.  Programming this way is okay to learn recursion, but continuing with it has tripped up several of my students in the long run.